# How do I react to a certain amount of time having elapsed since an event, in this webcam reading loop?

Tags: python, python-datetime, mediapipe

**AIM** I am making a posture detection system which detects whether a leg is bent or not and by extension counts the Reps done ( a successful rep is when the leg is bent for 8 seconds ). I am doing this by using the media pipe pose model, by calculating the angle between the left ankle, left knee and left hip ( landmarks ).

The aim is to run a countdown timer of 8 seconds as soon the angle becomes less than 140 degrees.

I have tried the following, I am trying to fix this for 2 days, but can't seem to do it.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import mediapipe as mp
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose



# Capturing/ Reading the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/ausaf/Downloads/KneeBendVideo.mp4')

counter = 0
stage = None
diff = 0


def calculate_angle(h, k, a):  # h=hip, k=knee, a=ankle
    h = np.array(h)  # hip
    k = np.array(k)  # knee
    a = np.array(a)  # ankle

    radians = np.arctan2(h[1] - k[1], a[0] - k[0]) - np.arctan2(h[1] - k[1], h[0] - k[0])
    angle = np.abs(radians * 180.0 / np.pi)

    #     if angle > 180:
    #         angle = 360 - angle

    return angle


# # Setup Mediapipe Instance
with mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.8, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # Recolor Image to RGB
        image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image.flags.writeable = False

        # Make Detection
        results = pose.process(image)

        # Recolor back to BGR
        image.flags.writeable = True
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # Extract Landmarks
        try:
            landmarks = results.pose_landmarks.landmark

            # Get Co-ordinates

            hip = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP.value].x,  landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP.value].y]
            knee = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_KNEE.value].x,
                    landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_KNEE.value].y]
            ankle = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ANKLE.value].x,
                     landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ANKLE.value].y]

            # Calculate Angle
            angle = calculate_angle(hip, knee, ankle)
            # print(calculate_angle(hip,knee,ankle))

            # visualize
            cv2.putText(image, str(angle),
                        tuple(np.multiply(knee, [854, 640]).astype(int)),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        except:
            pass

        # Render Rep Counter
        # Counter Box
        cv2.rectangle(image, (0, 0), (225, 73), (245, 117, 16), -1)

        # print Rep Counter to window
        cv2.putText(image, 'REPS', (15, 12),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(image, str(counter), (10, 60),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        # print Knee Bent Status
        cv2.putText(image, 'Knee Status', (65, 12),
                     cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(image, stage, (60, 60),
                     cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        # Render Detections
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                  mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245, 117, 66), thickness=2, circle_radius=2),
                                  mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245, 66, 230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2), )


        # Logic for rep counting **This is the problem**
        if angle > 140:
            stage = 'straight knee'
            
        while angle < 140 and stage == 'straight knee':
            # start timer, take current time
            start_time = datetime.now()
            stage = 'bent knee'
            diff = (datetime.now() - start_time).seconds

            # check if diff == 8
            while diff <= 8 :
                # print diff to putText
                cv2.putText(image, str(diff), (70, 70),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                diff = (datetime.now() - start_time ).seconds
                print(diff)
            # if the timer hits 8 seconds, increase rep count
            counter = +1
            
        # if the timer is not 0 and the angle becomes greater than 140 degrees (not bent), print feedback to window
        if angle > 140 and diff > 0:
            cv2.putText(image, 'keep your knees bent', (50, 50),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow('Mediapipe Feed', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, this code does countdown for 8 seconds ( which i know by printing 'diff' on the console), but the video output freezes for 8 seconds while its executing. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: not an opencv issue. you need to learn about "state machines". you did try to keep a state and react to changes in state, but the logic is incomplete and in the wrong places (prevents continuous video updates, which are the only thing that would change the state)

Comment: yes, I totally agree, I was, for some reason focused on OpenCV being the problem (maybe because I'm learning it), but it's very clear now that I read the code again, the logic was crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exit out of this loop only after 8 seconds, and during that time you never show the updated image (and you are not grabbing it from the camera).

```
while diff <= 8 :
        # print diff to putText
        cv2.putText(image, str(diff), (70, 70),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        diff = (datetime.now() - start_time ).seconds
        print(diff)
```

You need to create out of the scope next to the diff `start_time=None` and then replace both of the `while` with this:

```
if angle < 140 and stage == 'straight knee':
    # start timer, take current time
    start_time = datetime.now()
    stage = 'bent knee'

if start_time and stage == 'bent knee':
        diff = (datetime.now() - start_time ).seconds
        if diff <= 8:
            cv2.putText(image, str(diff), (70, 70),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            print(diff)
```

Comment: oh, now that you've pointed it out, it's obvious, btw, for someone trying something similar in future, this code needs some modifications for correctly counting reps, but as far as the question goes, this answer is on point. Thanks a lot :)